# Multiple lines of text next to image (CSS-HTML)

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am trying to put 2 lines of text next to an image, sort of like this

```
_________
|       | Line one of text
| image |
|       | Line two of text
---------
```

This is the code that I have so far

```
<p style="color: #fff;"><img src="assets/image.png"><span style="">Line one of text</span>
    <br>
    <span class="ban2">Line 2 of text</span></p>
```

```css
 .banner p {
  font-family: "Gentium Basic";
  font-size: 19px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #aaa;
  margin-top: -10;
  display: block;
 }
.banner img {
  float: center; 
    margin: 5px;
 }
 .banner span {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align:top;
 }
  .banner .ban2 span {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 17px;
  vertical-align:top;
 }
```

But currently it does this:

```
_________
|       | Line one of text
| image |
|       | 
---------
Line two of text
```

I have looked all over the web but have not been able to figure out how to do this, any help would be very welcome.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There's no such thing as `float: center;` You can choose either `left`, `right`, or `none`.

http://jsfiddle.net/vd7X8/1/

If you `float: left;` on the image it will do what you're after.

If you want it centered, then you're going to have to wrap the image and the text in a container, fix the width of the container and do `margin: 0 auto;` on it, then continue to have your image floated--except it will be constrained by the wrapper.

Comment: I am trying to center the image and text in a banner, if I make it float to the left then it goes all the way to the left without allowing me to make it centered.

Comment: If you want it centered, then you're going to have to wrap the image and the text in a container, fix the width of the container and do `margin: 0 auto;` on it, then continue to have your image floated--except it will be constrained by the wrapper. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/vd7X8/1/ (also updated answer.)

Answer (score 10):

Here is a snippet using a svg so you can test it anywhere.

```css
.img{
    float: left;
    margin-right:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <svg class="img" width="50" height="50" >
    <rect width="50" height="50" style="fill:black;"/>
  </svg>
  <p>
    Line 1
    <br>
    Line 2
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10):

Here is my demo which have using `float` and `overflow` with some explain

```css
.div1 {
     border: 3px solid #0f0;
     overflow:auto; // without overflow here, if the "Line 1" and "Line 2" is short then "Next elements" will display below "Line 2" and the image will cover the "Next elements" 
}
.img {
    float: left;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background: #000 
}
.div2 {
    float: left; // without float here, if "Line 1" and "Line 2" is long -> text will display both at right and bottom the image
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <img class="img"/>
  <div class="div2">
    <p> Line 1 </p>
    <p> Line 2 </p>
  </div>
</div>

<p>Next elements</p>
```

Hope it help

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I know this post is old but wrap your element in a `div` and apply the `vertical-align:top` to this `div` and you're done.

Comment: Yep, with some workaround that could be usable solution. Btw, post age doesn't matter, Q&A are here to provide help to other people too (facing same or similar problems).

Answer (score 1):

Check it. It is well defined css.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Selectors</title>
      <style>
         .banner p {
             font-family: "Gentium Basic";
             font-size: 19px;
             text-align: center;
             color: #aaa;
             margin-top: -10;
             display: block;
         }
         img, span {
             float:left;
         }
         .banner img {
             float: center; 
             margin: 5px;
         }
         [class="ban1"]{
             font-size: 17px;
             position:relative;
             top:50px;
             left:11px;
         }
         [class="ban2"] {
             font-size: 17px;
             position: relative;
             left: -97px;
             top: 74px;
         }
      </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div class="banner">
         <div class="wrapper">
            <p><img src="span.png"><span class="ban1">Line one of text</span>
               <span class="ban2">Line 2 of text</span>
            </p>
         </div>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This says float: center; that's not possible in css

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old post, but still wanted to say that not only `float` will do it, the `<img>` tag has a built-in attribute called `align="left"` which does that as well

```
<p>
 <img src="smiley.gif" align="left"><span>Line one of text</span>
 <br>
 <span class="ban2">Line 2 of text</span>
</p>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/356akcoy/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the old tables that works great. In terms of CSS it is just needed to add the `vertical-align: top` property.

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="img-container">
        <img src="https://img2.gratispng.com/20180324/sbe/kisspng-google-logo-g-suite-google-5ab6f1f0dbc9b7.1299911115219389289003.jpg"/>
      </td>
      <td class="content-container">
        <span class="description">This is a very long text that creates multiple lines with the image at left side</span>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Fiddle**: https://jsfiddle.net/fypa0k4w/